# How to send route props through <router-link>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

here is how my button which links to the route

```
 <router-link class="q-pa-md" :to="{ name: 'Edit'}" id="item.id">
    <q-btn outline>Edit</q-btn>
    </router-link>
```

> here is my router definition:

```
      { path: 'cms/index/edit/:id', name: 'Edit', component: () => import('components/cms/Edit.vue'), props: true },
```

Comment: How did my answer work out for you?

Comment: it worked, sorry  sir, I thought I had already accepted your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your `router-link`'s `:to` like:

```
:to="{ name: 'Edit', params: { id: item.id }}"
```

And you can remove the `id` attribute from the HTML element.  So, full code:

```
<router-link class="q-pa-md" :to="{ name: 'Edit', params: { id: item.id }}">
    <q-btn outline>Edit</q-btn>
</router-link>
```